# Constraint Layout, расположение элементов по вертикали с прилеганием к краям (поочередно)

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Подскажите общую идею, пожалуйста, тут нужно использовать флоу или есть какая-то другая хитрость?
Кол-во  элементов - любое. Главное условие - поочередное прилегание их к правому или левому краям родителя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здесь используется список: listview или recyclerview. Для айтема используется gravity, левый или правый край

Comment: @pavlofff благодарю!

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос на английском stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11202206/7566397 , думаю основные направления реализации будут понятны